# Creating a component from GatsbyLinkProps in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I am following this [guide](https://dev.to/jdcas89/start-your-app-the-right-way-featuring-react-styled-system-styled-components-and-typescript-7a4#typography) to try and build a couple of components for my application.

However, I am running to an error when trying to build a custom `Link` component using Gatsby's `Link` component.

**Typography.tsx**

```
import { Link as GLink, GatsbyLinkProps } from 'gatsby';

type GatsbyAnchorProps = StyledSystemProps & GatsbyLinkProps<any>;

const GatsbyLink: SFC<GatsbyAnchorProps> = ({ to, children, ...props }) => (
  <GLink to={to}>
    <DynamicStyledSystemComponent {...typographyStyles.Link} {...props}>
      {children}
    </DynamicStyledSystemComponent>
  </GLink>
);
```

**DynamicStyledSystemComponent.tsx**

```
export type StyledSystemProps =
  | SpaceProps
  | FontSizeProps
  | FontStyleProps
  | SizeProps
  | TextStyleProps
  | LetterSpacingProps
  | FontFamilyProps
  | FontWeightProps
  | BorderRadiusProps
  | FontFamilyProps
  | LineHeightProps
  | TextAlignProps
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  | {
      color: string;
      as?: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements | React.ComponentType<any>;
    };
```

**Error**

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
|   return (
>     <React.Fragment>
|       {finalData && render(finalData)}
|       {!finalData && <div>Loading (StaticQuery)</div>}
 @ ./src/components/atoms/typography/Typography.tsx 31:15-32
 @ ./src/components/atoms/typography/Typography.stories.tsx
```

How can i construct a custom Link type based of Gatsby's Link while baking in my styled-system in Typescript?

Comment: I am trying to do the exact same thing over here, and I ran into the exact same error. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Sorry @ShandySulen I don't think I ever reached a solution to this

Comment: No worries, and thanks for the response. Maybe one day...

Comment: not sure how you're using the StylesSystemProps, but could [this article](https://www.polynique.com/web-development/extend-gatsby-link-in-typescript/) help in your case?